# How can I use an if statement with this dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, dictionary

Here is my code

```
players = []
while len(players) >= 0:
    name = input('Enter a name: ')
    players.append(name)
    if name == '':
        players.pop()
        break
    else:
        pass             

player_dict = {name: [] for name in players}
print(player_dict)

for name in player_dict:
    answer = input(name + ', who will win the fight? ')
    player_dict[name].append(answer)

fight_winner = input('Who won the fight? ')

for name in player_dict:
    if answer == fight_winner:
        print(name + ' = Correct')
    else:
        print(name + ' = Incorrect')
print(player_dict)
```

This is what I see when I run the code

```
Enter a name: bill
Enter a name: bob
Enter a name: 
{'bill': [], 'bob': []}
bill, who will win the fight? red
bob, who will win the fight? blue
Who won the fight? red
bill = Incorrect
bob = Incorrect
{'bill': ['red'], 'bob': ['blue']}
```

I would expect to see `bill = Correct`. How can I access each indivuals value and run it through an if statement? Thank you for any help

Comment: you probably want something like `if fight_winner in player_dict[name]:`, but I don't understand why the player_dict values are lists.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for name in player_dict:
    if answer == fight_winner:
        print(name + ' = Correct')
    else:
        print(name + ' = Incorrect')
print(player_dict)
```

To:

```
for name, colors in player_dict.items():
    if fight_winner in colors:
        print(name + ' = Correct')
    else:
        print(name + ' = Incorrect')
print(player_dict)
```

Your `fight_winner` is color other than name. You stored color to a list as follows:

player_dict[name].append(answer)

The key is name, and the value is a list of colors. Therefore when you iterate dictionary `player_dict`, you should find the `name` based on color `fight_winner`

You cannot use variable answer in conditional statement `if answer == fight_winner:`, the reason is the value of answer is always assigned by the last iteration, and it may not gave you the right comparison.

For example, if the order is blue and then red, answer is red, and you set `fight_winner` to blue, both players would be `Incorrect`.

Below is my test:

```
python test.py                                  
Enter a name: bill
Enter a name: bob
Enter a name:
{'bill': [], 'bob': []}
bill, who will win the fight? red
bob, who will win the fight? blue
Who won the fight? red
bill = Correct
bob = Incorrect
{'bill': ['red'], 'bob': ['blue']}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, worked perfectly and thank you for the in depth explanation

Comment: @LukeBray glad it helps. Please check it as the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

In its current form, you can make your code work by changing:

```
if answer == fight_winner:
```

to:

```
if player_dict[name][0] == fight_winner:
```

Or (even better):

```
answer = player_dict[name][0]
if answer == fight_winner:
```

However, I don't see the need for each player's dictionary entry to be an list, since you are only storing a single value for each player. Consider using something like the following instead:

```
player_dict = {}

for name in players:
    answer = input(name + ', who will win the fight? ')
    player_dict[name] = answer

fight_winner = input('Who won the fight? ')

for name, answer in player_dict:
    if answer == fight_winner:
        print(name + ' = Correct')
    else:
        print(name + ' = Incorrect')
```

This approach seems more readable (at least, in my opinion), and doesn't use lists in the `player_dict`, since they are not necessary (in the current form of your code).

Comment: thanks for your help, your solution works. The reason I have a list is because I hope to have multiple values in the list eventually